# cannot hide a directory on Ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 20 on VMWare workstation 2016. I want to hide a directory. I create a directory and then rename it and add a '.' before the name (.dirname), but unfortunately directory isn't hidden yet.
When I open the desktop from "files" section, the directory is hidden, but when I check it from the desktop itself, the directory is shown for me and is not hidden.

What's wrong?

Comment: How are you viewing the "folder"? Don't you mean "directory"?

Comment: @Rob yes I mean directory

Comment: Ok but how are you viewing the files? with ls? With a graphical desktop file viewer?

Answer (score 2):

On Unix, there is no such thing than an hidden file or directory. The `.` prefix is just a convention followed by `ls` or the `*` pattern (and surely other programs) to avoid reporting these files or directories.

If you use a program which doesn’t follow this convention (like `ls -a`), the so called hidden files/directories are no longer hidden.

Comment: A hack that stuck: [How Dot Files Became Hidden Files](https://linux-audit.com/linux-history-how-dot-files-became-hidden-files/).